# Why we cannot touch Lord Shani idol?

Tags: gods, astrology, shani

I am not finding any answers for why someone should not touch Lord Shani idol, so I am asking here.

Last time I visited a Hanuman temple where as usual I touched feet of Hanuman and put on my eyes, then a person behind me said that I should not touch feet of Hanuman as that is the place of Shani god.

I visited Shirdi last week and touched the idol of Shani ( My son he being 3 years old touched the crow and put his hands on his eyes :) ), then immediately the public there mentioned to do not touch the idol.

As there are no Lord Shani temples in my area, I am not aware of this tradition to do not touch Shani idol.

Now I hope you understood my question, why we should not touch Shani idol and what are the remedies if we mistakenly touched?

Comment: actually only the priest can touch the idol of the temple be it any deity.

Comment: These are local customs. In my village many men and women goes to shani temple on Saturday and everyone touches the feet of statue.

Comment: Okay as far as the logic I know. When we touch someone's feet in reverance. The person is ought to look on us for blessing. But, as Shani has a vakra drishti this is quite harmful (I knw this is a lame logic tho). Secondly, the vigrahas in Garbhagriha must not be touched by everyone, keeping the Shauch-Ashauch in mind. The best answer comes from Kerala, as a Tanthri narrated, Naga aradhana & any puja for Navagraha must be done with extra care. In their upasana Shauch (cleanliness) of the pujari, shuddhi (purity) of pujasthala, Pujapatras, Dravyas used etc  are taken of special care.

Comment: Therefore, as aforesaid, the cleanliness holds such high value when it comes any Navagraha puja. Thus, we can say that, we as in person might not pay attention to these intricate details. Thus, it's for good to bar people from touching the idol itself.